# Переменное число именованных аргументов

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

имеется такое вот задание: самостоятельно подберите или придумайте задачу с переменным числом именованных аргументов и приведите решение этой задачи. Я придумал вот такую простенькую задачу: найти среднеквадратическое отклонение и минимальное значение в словаре.
И собственно говоря сам код:

```
def disp(**kwargs):
    n = len(kwargs.values())
    s = sum(kwargs.values())
    sigma = 0
    min_val = min(kwargs.values())
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if v == min_val:
            print(f"Наименьшая переменная {k} со значением {v}")
    for a in kwargs.values():
        sigma += (a - s) ** 2
    dev = (sigma / (n - 1)) ** 0.5
    print(f"Среднеквадратическое отклонение - {dev}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    disp(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=6, e=4, f=2)
```

При показе задания преподавателю, он сказал: не по пеп8 и ничего не понятно, с точки зрения построения задачи, словарь не подойдёт, должно быть что-то вразумительное. Это дословно. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить задачу, чтобы она подходила под все требования. Спасибо.

Comment: Отформатируйте код по-человечески.

Comment: Может как вариант использовать переменные по умолчанию?

Comment: Табуляция вроде нормальная, именование переменных тоже, не знаю к чему тут можно придраться из pep8 :) Поискал у себя пример для вашей задачки и нашел пример генерации строки sql-запроса: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/function_example/function_example.py#L16

Comment: Я не знаю, что именно у преподавателя с PEP8... Но вот вы в условиях пишите - найти в словаре... а что вы на вход функции подаете? disp(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=6, e=4, f=2) - это словарь?

Comment: Хах, а ведь и правда, словаря то и нет. Ну, а вообще, код соответствует заданию? И так понимаю нужно изменить условие след. образом: найти среднеквадратическое отклонение и минимальное значение в списке именованных аргументов.

Comment: PEP-8 не соответствует только последняя строка, должно быть: `disp(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=6, e=4, f=2)` Если придраться, можно ещё исправить: `sigma += (a -s) ** 2` и `dev = (sigma/(n-1)) ** 0.5` (пробелы останутся только у операций с низшим приоритетом)

Comment: Попробуйте задать вопрос на [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), только сформулируйте немного по другому. И учтите, что это англоязычный сайт.